# Figuring out when individual files are changed

Tags: c++

I'm working in C++ on windows. I have a list of files. Some (not all) of the files, are having text appended to them (deletion / modification never occurs).

I'm trying to find out whether a file has been modified. I plan on getting the file size (by opening the file with ifstream, putting the cursor at the end, and using tellg) and seeing if that changes. I'll be keeping a vector of file names and a vector of file sizes, and I'll be seeing if the file size in question changes.

Is there a better or more appropriate way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: why not use MD5 or SHA2?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, harper. I think I was just searching the wrong stuff on google. Thanks! @vard: If I don't need to, why go through the trouble of computing the MD5/SHA2?

Comment: If the file size stays constant it doesn't mean what file wasn't changed. So you can write your own checksum computing algorithm. But your idea is significant: if the file size was changed, it was definitely changed. The size determining is a less complex and it's enough in such situations.

Comment: @harper 's suggestion is definitely the way to go if you know your are running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking the following:

1. Modification time. If it is not changed - the file is probably not changed (supposing that modification time is not changed intentionally).
2. Size of file. If size of file is changed - the file is also changed.
3. Check some parts of the file. For example - first and last block (depends on how file is supposed to change). If they are changed - file is changed.
4. If all of above don't help, then check file entirely.

P.S. On Windows you can use [wait functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing handle created by [FindFirstChangeNotification function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to trace file system changes.

Hope this helps.

Thanks!